# Why do some traditional Catholics choose Confirmation in the Extraordinary Form over going with their parish Confirmation?

Tags: catholicism, confirmation, extraordinary-form-of-the-mass

I'm trying to figure out whether it is a good idea to attempt to get my kids confirm in the Extraordinary Form, while it lasts, or go through the regular parish way of doing things.  My family and I attend a Traditional Latin Mass and I missed the prior chance to have a few of my kids get confirmed that way.

However, I see a lot of merit in the normal catechetical process and formation.  It seems almost sneaky or in some way disobedient to go out of my way to circumvent the process that my parish and diocese has in place, even if I do need my pastor's sign off on it.

And yes, I'm going to ask a priest, I'm just wondering what the benefits that some Traditional Latin Mass going Catholics see in doing the EF Confirmation over and above doing it the normal way with their parish.

Comment: As long as you have ecclesial permission, there's absolutely nothing wrong with having confirmation done in the Extraordinary Form. It's not sneaky at all. You're being upfront about your intentions and getting permission.

Comment: @jaredad7 there is one thing that I think makes it go from "absolutely" nothing wrong to something utterly aggravating.  If you have a parish where there are 3-4 masses per weekend, and half all the families with Children go to the Latin mass and most of those kids get confirmed in the EF rite, then you wind up not having enough kids getting confirmed in the NO rite to get the Bishop come and confirm them, the kids are no longer in catechism together, not to mention the TLM'ers kids develop an awful superiority complex or disconnect from the Mass altogether.

Answer (score 2):

**Why do some traditional Catholics choose Confirmation in the Extraordinary Form over going with their parish Confirmation?**

Having been attached to the traditional form for now more than 40 years and had pray in that form in many different circumstances, I recall vividly the retired Abbot of Fontgombault saying, on more than one occasion, to such inquiries: ***The ancient forms of the liturgy are more conducive to their spirituality.***

There may be other reasons for attending the Extraordinary Form of the Mass and its’ many liturgical Rites, like a love of Latin, but the crux of the matter is in its’ conduciveness to the spirituality of those who long for these Liturgical Forms within the Rite of Pope St. Pius V.